# XSLT: escaping double quote

Tags: xslt, quote

I have XSLT code like:

```
<xsl:if test="product_name='3" Magnifier'">
             <attribute name="Business Unit">
             Consumer
             </attribute>   
</xsl:if>
```

the value **3" Magnifier** (has quote), I couldn't compare it with **product name** because of quote ambiguity. So how to escape double quote & resolve ambiguity.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (XML + XSLT) next time!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="product_name='3&quot; Magnifier'">
```